# ngFor inside ngFor with two components

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
<div *ngFor=" let item of data " >
  // some details
  <app-child [user]="item"></app-child>
</div>
```

and in my child:

```
<div *ngFor=" let element of user " >
  // some details
  <a> {{element.name}} </a>
<div>
```

I can't read anything in element, what is the right way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

parent component.ts:

```
    public data: any = [];


    //API CALLS

    this.result.forEach(item => {
     this.data.push(item);
    });
```

this is my `console.log(data)`
[image]

and inside it there is an array called (comments) and I want to ngFor it and read the comments inside it, In conclusion I want to ngFor my posts and each post ngFor its comments.

and this is my comments array
[image]

Comment: What does "can't read anything" mean exactly?

Comment: I mean if I read {{item.name}} it is okay, but if I read {{element.name}} it is undefined

Comment: Could you show the code of the two components and also the model

Comment: Please post a sample as JSON format, `comments` array does not show anywhere in your first picture.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are taking the user array in your child-component as input

```
@Input() user : User;
```

**EDIT**

It seems your child component is getting an object not an array, so don't use ngFor, directly use

```
<div  >  
  <a> {{user.name}} </a>
<div>
```

Comment: Yes it is like this

Comment: But I need ngFor because I have array inside array and I want in my parent component to print the big array and in the child print the small array (inside it)

Comment: You have only array of objects not array of areays

Comment: You want to loop over recipient?

Comment: I want to loop over comments, check my new updates please

Comment: So you need to use div *ngFor=" let element of user.comments " > in your child component

Comment: I tried that and inside the <div> I used <p>{{element.post_id}}</p> but nothing displayed

Comment: can you post a sample json of your result